# Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

Tags: java, ojdbc

Below is the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>/home/martyn/eclipse-workspace/Jars/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The file definitely exists at that location. And in eclipse > Java Resources > Maven dependencies, I can see ojdbc7.12.1.0.2 is listed there.

Also, I'd preferably load this dependency from the repo, like so:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

...but I get this red x error: `Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2` So, for now, I'm just putting the local JAR path in the pom.xml.

By the way, here's the Java code in Spring MVC:

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe");
    dataSource.setUsername("budget_admin");
    dataSource.setPassword("s3cret");

    return dataSource;
}
```

I know this code works as I have it running OK on my work Windows PC. I'm just trying to setup my home dev. Also, I can successfully sign in on SQL Developer using these credentials.

Any ideas why this driver cannot be loaded?

Comment: What does the documentation say about system dependencies? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

Comment: I don't know. I don't see this particular dependency as part of the JDK if that's what you mean. Am I looking in the wrong place ($JAVA_HOME/lib/)? What specifically are you referring to in this link with reference to this problem?

Comment: Well, you chose to use a system dependency. The documentation says that they are for dependencies that are part of the JDK. And you now correctly say that it's not part of the JDK. So, why do you expect this to work, and thus why did you choose to use a system dependency, since you know, as per the dcumentation, that it can't possibly work?

Comment: Ideally I'd load it from the repository but no joy. So, I'm trying to load it from the file system (not JDK though, as you can see). If not `<scope>system</scope>`, what else should I have for scope to include a local non-JDK JAR library? Or, how do I pull this library from the repo and include it that way? I've tried the XML snippet that mvnrepository.com provided but it doesn't seem to get included, but other dependencies I've taken from there (e.g. org.json) do get included.

Comment: Put it in your local repository, or in your company's repository. Or use a better build tool (gradle), that allows using local files in addition to repositories.

Comment: I've put it in my local repository like so - https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/ - seems to have got me over that hurdle anyway. Thanks